# Fastest way to find counts of integral values (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I need an occurrence count for each occurring value from a list of unsigned integrals. I.e. if passed the sequence [ 3, 6, 9, 3, 9 ] I would want [ { 3, 2}, {6, 1}, {9, 2} ].

The values are random 32 bit unsigned ints (Range of 1 to 1,000,000,000). The result can be stored in any data structure (as long as they can be iterated over linearly) and whilst value ordered would be ideal this is a secondary concern after speed.

Currently I have -

```
T UniqueCount(std::vector<unsigned> &A)
{
    std::unordered_map<unsigned,unsigned> value_counts;

    for(unsigned val : A) {
        value_counts[val]++;
    }

    A.clear();

    ...
}
```

Profiling has shown std::unordered_map to be faster than std::map.

Is there a better approach for this? / Faster way? It is also worth noting because of the use case (count > 4) can be recorded as 4.

This is currently a bottleneck so whilst standard containers are preferred something custom can be considered if the performance boost is worth the additional maintenance cost.

Comment: PS you can just store the counts directly into `_vals`, like replace everything in your loop with `_vals[*it] ++` (or `value_counts[*it] ++` or whatever, hard to tell), because `operator []` [inserts an item with a default value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) (0 in your case) and returns a reference to the value.

Comment: Thanks - @krzaq suggested the same thing. Updated my code to that.

Comment: You might want to explain why this code is a bottleneck.   Is a new set of random values being regenerated frequently?   If so, why not generate the count in the process of generating the random values, rather than after?   Also (minor) bear in mind that `unsigned` is not guaranteed able to represent 32-bit values, so there is a potential concern of correctness when porting code.

Comment: `A` is passed as a non-const reference – is it allowed to be modified? Specifically, is it allowed to be sorted?

Comment: @ildjarn Yep - its fine to modify it. But sorting is going to be nlogn whereas the current code is O(N). Saying that I haven't profiled it with a sort.

Comment: @Peter - The values are passed to us like this. Getting it changed is possible but office politics and all that. And in either case the overhead of the for loop is going to be minimal compare to the lookup structure.

Comment: @user2036256 - That's not actually answering the question of why this code is a bottleneck.   How often is a new set of values passed, and how often are the counts actually needed?

Comment: @Peter - The code is taking approximately 0.03s to run on the larger blocks. The receiving thread at peak has started to receive the blocks faster than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system (Win10 x64, [MSVC daily package](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/04/26/stay-up-to-date-with-the-visual-c-tools-on-nuget/) x64 release build), testing with 100,000 random unsorted values in the input vector, the following using `std::sort` + `std::adjacent_find` performs in ~10ms vs. ~27ms using `std::unordered_map` and the code in @krzaq's answer (and now in the OP):

```
std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>> unique_count(std::vector<unsigned>& a) {
    auto it = begin(a);
    auto const last = end(a);

    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>> value_counts;
    std::sort(it, last);
    while (it != last) {
        auto const prev = it;
        it = std::adjacent_find(it, last, std::not_equal_to<unsigned>{});
        if (it != last) {
            ++it;
        }
        value_counts.emplace_back(*prev, static_cast<unsigned>(it - prev));
    }
    return value_counts;
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/892d5342de4d0894)</kbd>

The lesson: often, cache coherency beats algorithmic complexity.

Comment: +1 for doing actual benchmarks. Is there a reason why you're using `adjacent_find` instead of `upper_bound`? The latter seems to be the natural choice to me.

Comment: @krzaq : `upper_bound` bounces around over all remaining input, destroying the cache coherency that was the original point. That said, it's pretty close in performance – [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea215966b46cdb50) nets ~13ms on my system vs `adjacent_find`'s ~10ms. EDIT: This is probably a larger indicator of MSVC's lackluster `unordered_map` implementation than anything else.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to shave about 20% off with a typical dataset. Might experiment with radixsort to see if I can get that down further and fix the complexity for if this scales further!

Comment: @ildjarn Boost's spreadsort is based on MSD radix sort, so probably slower (by their own admission) than a well-tuned LSD radix sort. Radix sort certainly won't pale in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

If the range of your values is reasonable (i.e. you don't run out of memory doing what I'm about to suggest), you can use an array or a `vector`, e.g. for range [0, max_value] (untested but you get the idea):

```
// init
vector<int> counts(max_value + 1, 0);

// increment:
counts[value] ++;
```

Or you could dynamically resize as needed:

```
// init
vector<int> counts;

// increment:
if (value >= counts.size())
    counts.resize(value + 1, 0);
counts[value] ++;
```

If the range is reasonable but negative you can add an offset to make all the values non-negative, or maintain a separate vector for negative numbers and use their absolute values.

Otherwise, a hash map is pretty much the way to go, so you've pretty much hit your limit -- you could continue experimenting with `unordered_map` but provide a different [hash function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) that gives a more uniform distribution of hash values for your typical data.

Other ideas:

- Parallelize the counts - count chunks of the vector on multiple threads and either a) combine them at the end or b) test performance with atomic increment counters (e.g. `InterlockedIncrement` on Windows, although... you'd still need thread-safe inserts for new values so maybe stick with A). Couldn't tell you if a or b would be faster, you'd have to test. Use a thread-pool or some other pre-created threads, since you probably don't want the full overhead of starting and stopping threads each time.
- If you get long runs of the same value, or many short runs, you could perhaps cache a map iterator to the previous value. Then if the value you're about to look at is the same re-use that iterator and save yourself the hash lookup. I can't see this making much of a difference though but I don't know, you'd have to try it with your particular data set.

I can't really think of much else.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the range is up to 1,000,000,000 so this isn't really feasible.

Comment: @user2036256 Ah yeah, that's a bit much. Do you hit all 1,000,000,000 values or is the distribution pretty sparse within that range?

Comment: Average case ~100,000 entries which are fairly random within that range. Unlikely to hit more than 1,000,000 entries as things currently stand.

Comment: @user2036256 Are those values in a pretty random order (they are in your example but just confirming) or do you tend to get long runs of the same value (or even short runs, but many of them)?

Comment: Values appear random & in random order. Although there are more duplicates than you would expect with a truly random sequence.

Comment: @user2036256 I added a couple other suggestions. Personally my next step would be to count chunks of the vector in parallel on separate threads.

Comment: Thanks again. Parallellisation might be a good option. I'll look into whether the overhead of spinning up the threads is worth it.

Comment: @user2036256 If you do this operation multiple times throughout your application, you can use a fixed thread pool or some other set of pre-created threads, so you can keep reusing the threads instead of creating/destroying them every time.

Comment: @user2036256 If you first divide each value by 256, what fraction of the resulting numbers are unique? If the fraction is low (~10% or less) there's an easy way to handle the majority of cases which should give massive speed-ups. A uniformly random distribution with the range and quantity you give would give only ~1% collisions, FWIW.